# Sending JSON with AJAX to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Good afternoon,

I am trying to send some values from a text form (made by Gravity Form) to a PHP file where I can then send those values to an API (Insightly). The reason for this is Insightly does not take AJAX calls.

The code I have is below, when I click the submit button I keep getting the "Failed To Send" error defined below, it never succeeds. So far I haven't finished my PHP scripting, I only have the following line:

```
$obj = $_POST['myData'];
```

I've been researching this issue for awhile now and still can't figure it out. Any assistance is greatly appreciated! Without further ado, here is the Javascript I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#gform_submit_button_1").click(function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("input_1_19").value;
    // split name into first and last names
    var fname = name.split(" ")[0];
    var lname = name.split(" ")[1];
    var company = document.getElementById("input_1_15").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("input_1_6").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("input_1_14").value;
    var hearAbout = document.getElementById("input_1_10").value;
    var solution = document.getElementById("input_1_11").value;
    var market = document.getElementById("input_1_17").value;
    var details = document.getElementById("input_1_5").value;

    var information =
    {
        "fname": fname,
        "lname": lname,
        "company":company,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone,
        "hearAbout": hearAbout,
        "solution": solution,
        "market": market,
        "details": details
    };

var dataString = JSON.stringify(information);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "insightlyAPI.php",
        data: {myData: dataString},
        success: function(data){
            alert('AJAX Success!');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Failed To Send');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Need to inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues.

Comment: Make your error `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(textStatus);console.log(errorThrown);console.log(jqXHR);}` and post it's output here. BTW, it's not a good idea to debug with alerts...

Comment: I used the browser dev tools and it gave me the following:

parsererror

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
at Object.parts(native)
at m.parseJSON (http://localhost/InsightlyPHP/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:15948)
at Pc (http://localhost/InsightlyPHP/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:18329)
at x (http://localhost/InsightlyPHP/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:21743)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (http://localhost/InsightlyPHP/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4:25980)

Object {readystate: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

@Nordenheim thank you, I changed my error to match your recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) parameter you pass to `$.ajax` call tell jQuery to expect data from the server:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.

Try to return json from your PHP script, for example, add at the end:

```
echo json_encode(array());
```

Comment: Thank you Boris, my code now validates properly as long as I have the browser debugger open.